# Closing Http response stream in NodeJS before it ends

Tags: node.js, http, csv, stream

I am using requests module in nodejs to make a request and I am streaming response I got. This response stream is piped to csv parser and populating records onto an array. Once I get a preset count of records, I want to end csv parsing and close the response stream. How do I properly cleanup response stream. Here is the pseudo code

```
var stream = request.get(url);
stream.pipe(csvParser);
var count = 15;
csvParser.on("readable",function(){
    while(record = csvParser.read()){
        if(records.length<count){
            records.push(record);
        } else {
            csvParser.end();
            //stream.close();
            //stream.unpipe();
            // stream.destroy();
        }
    }
});

csvParser.on("error",function(err){
    console.log("Error",err.message);
})

csvParser.on("finish",function(){
    //console.log("records",records);
    console.log("done");
})
```

when I try stream.close() , it's saying undefined method. What's the correct way of cleaning it up..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `close` method for readable stream. `close` method is old hack to close only `fs` read stream (I do not know if it's still working)

Also there is no method `destroy` in readable stream.

I'm afraid there is no method to end stream before it ends.

You can stop reading from stream. In your case stream work in `flowing mode`, therefore this method `csvParser.read()` when is called, is requests for next parts of data. If you stop calling `csvParser.read()` then this event `csvParser.on("readable",function(){` stopped to fire.

There is some good conversation https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nodejs/eGukJUQrOBY/URD8I7tNxRUJ about similar case.