# How to end a http response stream when the size of the accumulated chunks is larger than a threshold

Tags: node.js, http, request

I'm trying to download some files from a list of urls but I don't want to download anything that's over a certain size (let's say 1mb). The files could be gigabytes, so I need a way to cancel the download as soon as the response stream grows larger than 1mb.

```
let request = require("request");
function getFile(url, callback) {
  request.get(url)
  .on('response', function(response) {
    let output = "";
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      if(output.length > 1000000) {
        // ??? ABORT STREAM HERE ???
        console.log(`${url} is too big`);
        callback(true);
      } else {
        output += chunk.toString("utf8");
      }
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log(`${url} download complete`);
      callback(null, output);
    });
  });
}
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this. [This github issue for the request library](https://github.com/request/request/issues/772) talks about aborting a request, but I think that I want to abort the actual *http response stream* rather than the request. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416411/993683) but the answerer seemed to suggest that it isn't possible. I'm sure this isn't true (or I've misinterpreted their answer) because otherwise I'd be forced to download every 10gig file I came across.

Is it as simple as removing the `data` and `end` event listeners? Intuitively I'd guess that the download continues whether there's events attached or not, but I really have no idea how it all works behind the scenes. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-stats

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295689/how-to-get-byte-size-of-request

Comment: once u got the size then i think u can easily cancel it

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit more with this and it turns out that the `request` package's `.abort()` method *does* cancel the http response stream.

I was hoping for a more generic way to cancel a http response stream that doesn't depend on the request package, but this will do for my purposes since I am currently using the request library.

```
let request = require("request");

function getFile(url, callback) {
  let tooBig = false;
  let r = request.get(url)
    .on('error', callback)
    .on('response', function(response) {
      let output = "";
      response.on('error', function(error) {
        callback(error, null);
      });
      response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        if(output.length > 1000000) {
          tooBig = true;
          r.abort();
        } else {
          output += chunk.toString("utf8");
        }
      });
      response.on('end', function() {
        if(tooBig) {
          console.log(`${url} was too big`);
          callback("too big", null);
        } else {
          console.log(`${url} download complete`);
          callback(null, output);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Also, if you're using the request library then it turns out things can be simplified a bit more:

```
function getFileSimplified(url, callback) {
  let output = "";
  let tooBig = false;
  let r = request.get(url)
    .on('error', callback)
    .on('data', function(chunk) {
      if(output.length > 1000000) {
        tooBig = true;
        r.abort();
      } else {
        output += chunk.toString("utf8");
      }
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      if(tooBig) {
        console.log(`${url} was too big`);
        callback("too big", null);
      } else {
        console.log(`${url} download complete`);
        callback(null, output);
      }
    })
}
```

Hope that helps people who ran into a similar problem. I'm not going to accept this answer, because the correct answer to the question as asked should not depend on the npm request package. If anyone knows how to do that, please post another an answer and I'll accept it.